# Python printing a string yields an unexpected result

Tags: python, string, jython

Trying to print / work with a specific String is driving me crazy in Python - or to specify this: I am using Jython.

The simple command

```
print "appilog.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx"
```

results in a print of something looking like a java package

```
com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx
```

Does Python/Jython do any special lookup for strings? Is there a way to enforce the usage of the "original" string I entered before? 
Other things I tried are the following:

```
print ("appilog...")
print r"appilog..."
print str("appilog...")
print str(r"appilog...")
```

Imports used in the script this command is located in are the following:

```
from com.hp.ucmdb.discovery.probe.services.dynamic.core import EnvironmentInformation
#coding=utf-8
import string
import re
import sys
import os
import ConfigParser 
import shutil      
import StringIO
import logger
import modeling
import time
import subprocess           

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport;
import javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;

import datetime
from appilog.common.system.types.vectors import ObjectStateHolderVector
```

Comment: In python console i get the expected result.

Comment: I suspect that Python is doing some kind of lookup matching strings thatr are written like "a.b.c.d" to class or package names. I am just wondering if there is a way to enfore the print of a string, without any replacement of the ASCII characters. Like `print "\n"` would print a linebreak whereas `print "\\n"` would print the desired \n

Comment: @schneiti: Python does no such thing. `print()` writes bytestrings *unaltered* to `sys.stdout`. Are you sure you are not wrapping Python with something else?

Comment: to check if it's the print you can try `str("appilog.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx" )`

Comment: @Bob: using a string literal (creating a value with quotes) **always** produces a string object. Passing that to `str()` is redundant and won't change anything. But it is *not standard Python behaviour* to alter what is printed anyway.

Comment: @schneiti how do you launch your command (via the Jython prompt via a script or other way ?)

Comment: @XavierCombelle The command is launched in a script, which has some imports. None of them are known to me to overwrite the print function. I added the imports in the Question!

Comment: To debug – does the same thing happen if you just run the print statement? e.g. `jython -c "print('appilog.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx')"`

Comment: Do you get the same symptom with `sys.stdout.write('appilog.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxxx\n')`? Is it possible that one of your imports messes with `print`?